# why ALL(SELECT) doesn't work to get max value

Tags: sql, aggregation

I'm working on Weather Observation Station 15 from Hackerrank ([Hackerrank Question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-15/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen))

It asked

> Query the Western Longitude (LONG_W) for the largest Northern Latitude (LAT_N) in STATION that is less than 137.2345 . Round your answer to decimal places.

STATION Table got 5 columns: ID, CITY, STATE, LAT_N, LONG_W.

Below is the my query and I'm trying to figure out why it does not work.

```
SELECT ROUND(LONG_W, 4) FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N >= ALL(SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N < '137.2345')
```

When I tried a different query and this works

```
SELECT ROUND(LONG_W, 4) FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N = (SELECT MAX(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N < '137.2345')
```

What's wrong with the first query? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT ROUND(LONG_W, 4) FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N >= ALL(SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N < '137.2345')
```

will return all the rows where `LAT_N` is greater or equal to `'137.2345'` because it is missing an additional condition.

It should have been written as:

```
SELECT ROUND(LONG_W, 4) FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N <  '137.2345'
  AND LAT_N >= ALL(SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N < '137.2345')
```

Answer (score 0):

This query :

```
select round (long_w,4)
from station
where lat_n<137.2345
order by lat_n desc
limit 1;
```

**firstly**, it is selecting all rows with lat_n less than 137.2345.

**secondly,** it orders the result by lat_n in descending order so the first
row has the largest lat_n that is less than 137.2345.

**Thirdly,** I set a limit equal to 1 to only get the first row, then I get the round of long_w using the round function.

**Syntax**
ROUND(number, decimals, operation)